# How to get raw message before it is sent by NodeMailer?

Tags: nodemailer

is it possible to get the raw message from NodeMailer before it is sent? My goal is to capture the properly formatted message so that I can append it to an IMAP Sent mailbox, instead of manually having to create the message myself, which to me seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mailcomposer` to create a `readSream` or `buffer` of a raw rfc822 message.

1) Require mailcomposer in your script. it is part of nodemailer:

```
const MailComposer = require('nodemailer/lib/mail-composer')
```

2) Create a new MailComposer instance:

```
var mail = new MailComposer(mailOptions)
```

Where mailOptions is an object that defines the components of the message, see below.

3) Now you can either create a read stream:

```
var mail = new MailComposer({from: '...', ...})
var stream = mail.compile().createReadStream()
stream.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Or you can generate the message buffer:

```
var mail = new MailComposer({from: '...', ...})
mail.compile().build(function(err, result){
  process.stdout.write(result)
})
```

To read more about the components of the message check the [documentation of Mailcomposer](http://nodemailer.com/extras/mailcomposer/)